# How can I change the block-code style for Markdown in Atom?

Tags: less, markdown, atom-editor

I added the following to my style.less to customize my Markdown preview.

I modified an existing file but one thing isn't working: I can't change the look of the block-code. If it's right, the very last part of my document, beginning by "`pre {`" should modify the appearance of my block code, but it doesn't. Why?

```
pre {
  padding: 0;
  padding-top: 0.333em; //Espace au dessus du code
  padding-bottom: 0.167em; //Espace en dessous du code
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 85%; //Taille de la font
  background-color: rgba(92,62,33,1); //Couleur de la ligne : Marron2/6
  border-radius: 6px; // Rayon des angles
  color: #EBE1D8; //Couleur de la font : Marron6/6
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `pre` to `.markdown-preview.markdown-preview code`.

[Source](https://atom.io/packages/markdown-preview)

Comment: This changes the look of the inline code not the code blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Code blocks can be targetted with `code {` instead of `pre {`